# Return data from a Java process back to calling C#. Possible?

Tags: c#, java, process

I'll explain breifly my situation and hopefully you will be able to advise if what im wanting to do is possible.

I have an existing java application that I am wanting to split into modules. To handle and control these modules Im going to write a module manager in C#.net. Due to the size of the existing program the bulk of the existing modules are not going to be rewritten in .net yet and remain as java modules.

Is it possible to call a java "module", pass it parameters and have the java module return a value ( other than an int )?

I apologise for not knowing much about this area.

Kind Regards

Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... maybe some kind of MessageQueues like MSMQ, Apache ActiveMQ or IBM WebsphereMQ can solve your problem.

On the queues you can store and receive XML-Messages with all the Information you need.

Some information about this can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973816.aspx

Another approch can be to work with console output .. but IMHO this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would instantiate the Java as a separate service and call it using (say) web services, [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) etc.

Alternatively, have you looked at [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: I have been looking at both webservices and jni4net. I couldnt get the examples from jni4net running and havent had chance to try and debug properly yet. With the webservices I have made quite a bit of progress. I have a .net client talking to a WCF service with duplex binding. I have an issue that my java WS cannot communicate with the WCF service as java cant interop with dualhttpbinding. I have since been told you can add multiple bindings to the WCF service and have the java WS connect to the basic one. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: maybe this article can help you: http://romenlaw.blogspot.com/2008/07/consuming-wcf-web-service-using-java.html

Answer (score 1):

If everything's in Java, then why the effort in moving everything to C#? From what you've said it'd make much more sense to write the module manager in Java and just keep the codebase all in one language (unless of course I'm missing something, in which case ignore!)

If you really need to do this then I'd say a web service is the nicest way to go, there's other hacks and various [tools](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) around that you could use, but a web service would completely abstract the language away and makes things much easier to consume.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your Java module as a soap web-service and consume it from C#.

[Here](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html) you can read about Axis one of the Java Soap engines and [quick tutorial](http://blogs.epfl.ch/article/409) how to create and call it from C#.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this either but hopefully reading this thread helps you...  :)

[Java - C# interop](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t140810-java-c-interop.html)